# Describe, as a direct sum of cyclic groups, given a map $\phi: \mathbb{Z}^{3} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to resolve the next one:

> Describe, as a direct sum of cyclic groups, the cokernel of the map $\phi: \mathbb{Z}^{3} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{3}$ given by left multiplication by the matrix
>
> $$
> \left(\begin{matrix} 15 & 6 & 9 \\ 6 & 6 & 6 \\ -3 & -12 & -12 \end{matrix}\right)
> $$

So, the cokernel is $\mathbb{Z}^{3}/\phi(\mathbb{Z}^{3})$, I know that I can only get at most two groups of order 3, but I'm not able to describe it. Any hint?

Comment: You have to put the matrix into Smith Normal Form.

Comment: Relevant links: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546751/finding-an-explicit-isomorphism-from-mathbbz4-h-to-mathbbz-oplus-m/1548318#1548318), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586353/how-to-recognize-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-as-a-product-of-cyclic-group/1604950#1604950)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Derek Holt and SpamIAM for the recomendations and useful links, after a while to read and understand  [Modules over a PID](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/modulesoverPID.pdf), I finally got an answer.

Let $\phi$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map such that can be determined by $\phi(e_{1}) = f_{1}, \dots,  \phi(e_{n}) = f_{n}$, where $e_{1}, \dots, e_{n}$ be the basis of $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$. Then $\phi(e_{j}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} = c_{ij}e_{i}$ for $j = 1, \dots, n$, so $(c_{ij})$ is the matrix representation of $\phi$ with respect to the basis. Then

$$
\phi(\mathbb{Z}^{n}) = \mathbb{Z}\phi(e_{1}) \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}\phi(e_{n}) = \mathbb{Z}f_{1} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}f_{n},
$$

By aligned bases for $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ and its modulo $\phi(\mathbb{Z}^{n})$, we can say that

$$
\mathbb{Z}^{n} = \mathbb{Z}v_{1} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}v_{n}, \hspace{1 em} \phi(\mathbb{Z}^{n}) = \mathbb{Z}a_{1}v_{1} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}a_{n}v_{n}
$$

where $a_{i}$'s are nonzero integers. Then

$$
\mathbb{Z}^{n}/\phi(\mathbb{Z}^{n}) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{b} \mathbb{Z}/a_{i}\mathbb{Z}
$$

Now, for our solution we need to get the [Smith Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), since each $a_{i}$ is the $M_{i,i}$ element of the matrix, the Smith Normal Form of the cokernel is:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 18
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

So, we can describe the cokernel as the sum of cyclic groups:

$$
\mathbb{Z}^{3}/\phi(\mathbb{Z}^{3}) \cong  \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}
$$