# Find a base for $\mathbb Z$-submodule of of $\mathbb Z^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I Want to find a basis for $\mathbb Z$-submodule of of  $\mathbb Z^3$ satisfing the conditions below:

$x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0 , x_1+4x_2+9x_3=0$

I don't know where to start from. I see that this submodule should be free as $\mathbb Z$ is a P.I.D. and this submodule should be some $M$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^3/K$ where K is the Kernel of following homomorphism.

$\mu:\mathbb Z^3 \to M $

how should I form this kernel and find the basis?

Comment: There are many posts on this topic.  See here: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586353/how-to-recognize-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-as-a-product-of-cyclic-group), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546751/finding-an-explicit-isomorphism-from-mathbbz4-h-to-mathbbz-oplus-m), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186634/how-to-draw-a-sublattice-to-exhibit-diagonalization), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422919/suggestions-for-computing-mathbbzi3-k-where-k-langle1-2-1-0-0-5/)