# what is the order of the quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{12})/\left \langle (4, 10) \right \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\left \langle (4, 10) \right \rangle$ is the cyclic subgroup of the abelian group of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$, 
what is the order of the quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{12})/\left \langle (4,  10) \right \rangle$?

Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: What are your own thoughts about how to solve this?

Comment: You may find [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856306/how-to-find-mathbb-z-12-times-mathbb-z-12-a4-a6#comment5891731_2856306) on a similar question helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{12})/ \langle (4, 10)  \rangle
\cong
(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/ \langle (4, 10), (0,12) \rangle
$$
Therefore, the group has $48$ elements, because
$$
\begin{vmatrix}  4 & 10 \\ 0 & 12 \end{vmatrix} = 48
$$
If you want to determine *which* group it is, compute the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of this matrix.