# Is $M=\frac{\mathbb{Z}^3}{\langle (3,3,1),(2,2,2)\rangle}$ free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, quotient-spaces, free-modules

I'm trying to solve a question which asks me to determine whether the quotient $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M=\frac{\mathbb{Z}^3}{\langle (3,3,1),(2,2,2)\rangle}$ is free. I'm then supposed to find some element of $M$ of infinite order.

I'm really new to modules and finding them hard to wrap my head around, so would appreciate any help you could offer/hints you could give me.

EDIT: while a similar question has been asked here -
 [Show that $M=\frac{\mathbb{Z}^3}{\langle (3,3,1),(2,2,2)\rangle}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151388/show-that-m-frac-mathbbz3-langle-3-3-1-2-2-2-rangle-is-isomorphic) - the answers there use the fact $M$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$. I'd like to show that it isn't free more directly if at all possible. Would appreciate any help anyone could offer.

Comment: $(1,1,1)$ is obviously a torsion element. Free modules are torsion-free.

Comment: Also, applying elementary row and column operations really is very short and direct, as done at the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151388/show-that-m-frac-mathbbz3-langle-3-3-1-2-2-2-rangle-is-isomorphic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $M=\frac{\mathbb{Z}^3}{\langle (3,3,1),(2,2,2)\rangle}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151388/show-that-m-frac-mathbbz3-langle-3-3-1-2-2-2-rangle-is-isomorphic)