# Finding a necessary and sufficient condition for a free abelian group of rank $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

> Let $V=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\ \mu\\ \nu\end{pmatrix}\colon \lambda,\mu,\nu\in\mathbb Z\right\}$, so $V$ is a free abelian gorup of rank $3$.
>
> Suppose that $a=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\alpha_3\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}\beta_1\\\beta_2\\\beta_3\end{pmatrix}$ are in $V$. Let $U$ be the subgroup of $V$ generated by $a$ and $b$. Assume that $U$ has rank $2$.
>
> State and prove a necessary and sufficient condition involving the three determinants $\begin{vmatrix}\alpha_1&\beta_1\\\alpha_2&\beta_2\end{vmatrix}$, $\begin{vmatrix}\alpha_1&\beta_1\\\alpha_3&\beta_3\end{vmatrix}$, and $\begin{vmatrix}\alpha_2&\beta_2\\\alpha_3&\beta_3\end{vmatrix}$, insuring that $V/U$ is free abelian of rank $1$.

---

**My attempt:**

If $V/U$ is a free abelian of rank $1$, then there exist two invertible matrices $A\in M_3(\mathbb Z)$ and $B\in M_2(\mathbb Z)$ such that $A[a\ b]B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. But how am I supposed to find a necessary and sufficient condition involving the three determinants?

Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

---

Addendum: The minors may not be preserved under elementary transformations.

Comment: Where is this from?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an **outline** for one possible way to think about this.

*Also I notice that I have answered the transpose of your question. Just take the transpose of all the matrices I have written down. The ideas are still the same.*

As you have realised yourself, the group theory part of the question is just realising that you need the Smith Normal Form to be 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

It seems that you are happy with this and this is a standard exercise. If you are not happy with this, see the [excellent answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721523/smith-normal-form-and-classification-of-factor-groups-according-to-the-theorem-o) by Derek Holt.

The tricky part, is the following.

> Find a necessary and sufficient condition involving the minor determinants $\begin{vmatrix} a_1&a_2 \\ b_1&b_2 \end{vmatrix},  \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_3 \end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix} a_2 & a_3 \\ b_2 & b_3 \end{vmatrix}$ for the matrix $$T =\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3\\b_1&b_2&b_3\end{bmatrix} $$ to have Smith Normal Form as above.

We will need the following Theorems about existence and uniqueness of the Smith Normal Form.
These Theorems are 5.8 and 5.11 in the [typed notes here](http://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Classes/700c/notes2.pdf).

> **Theorem** *Existence of Smith Normal Form*
>
> Let $R$ be an Euclidean domain. Then every $A \in M_{m \times n}(R)$
>   is equivalent to a diagonal matrix of the form
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}f_1 & \\ & f_2 \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & f_{r} \\ & & &
>  & 0 \\ & & & & & \ddots \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> where $ f_{1} \mid f_{2} \mid \dots \mid f_{r-1} \mid f_{r} $ .

And we need

> **Theorem** *Uniqueness of Smith Normal Form*
>
> Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain and let $A \in M_{ m \times n} (R) $ and let 
>   $$ S = \begin{bmatrix}f_1 & \\ & f_2 \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & f_{r} \\ & & & & 0 \\ & & & &  & \ddots \end{bmatrix} $$ be a Smith normal form of $A$. Then the gcd of $k \times k$ sub-determinants of $$A = \begin{cases} f_{1}f_{2} \dots f_{k}, \; 1\leq k \leq r \\ 0, r<k \leq k \leq min\{m,n\} \end{cases}. $$
>   Therefore the elements $f_{1}, f_{2}, \dots, f_{r}$ are unique up to multiplication by units.

We note here [that $R = \mathbb{Z}$ is an Euclidean domain.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integers_are_Euclidean_Domain)

We will prove the following

> **Claim** The matrix $T$ has Smith normal form $$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ if and only if the greatest common divisor of the three minor determinants $$\begin{vmatrix} a_1&a_2 \\ b_1&b_2 \end{vmatrix},  \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_3 \end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix} a_2 & a_3 \\ b_2 & b_3 \end{vmatrix}$$ is $1$.

**Proof**. First suppose that the matrix $T$ has Smith normal form $ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then by the Uniqueness Theorem above, we know that the greatest common divisor of $a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1, b_2, b_3$ is $1$ (since the first element on the diagonal is $f_{1} = 1$). Then since the second element on the diagonal is $f_{2}=1$, we know that the greatest common divisor of the three $2 \times 2$ Determinants
$\begin{vmatrix} a_1&a_2 \\ b_1&b_2 \end{vmatrix},  \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_3 \end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix} a_2 & a_3 \\ b_2 & b_3 \end{vmatrix}$ is equal to $f_{1} f_{2} = 1$.

Conversely suppose that the gcd of the determinants of the $2 \times 2$ Submatrices is $1$. Notice that this implies that the gcd $g$ of $(a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1, b_2,b_3)=1$ since  this number divides the determinants of all the $2 \times 2$ minors. By the Existence Theorem of the Smith Normal Form, we know that $T$ has Smith Normal Form

$$ \begin{bmatrix} f_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & f_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}. $$
By the Uniqueness of Smith Normal form and the observations about $gcd$ above, we see that $f_{1}=1$ and $f_{2}=1$.

Comment: Are you sure that "the minor determinants have their values preserved" claimed in the paragraph below $$N=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ What about adding the last column to the second column and consider the minor formed by the first column and the second?

Comment: Sorry @Bach you are absolutely right. My original solution was wrong. I hope I have fixed things now and I have given references for my claims.