# Quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

What is $\mathbb{Z}^2/\left( (m,n)\mathbb{Z} \right)$ where $m, n$ are bigger than one and co-prime? Since it is abelian it must be $\mathbb{Z}^r$ plus some torsion but I can't figure out what it is precisely.

Comment: Other hint: What's the order of the group? What's the order of $(1, 1)$?

Comment: @ConnorHarris well I can show that there are no elements of finite order. Probably I should make the question more precise. I cant determine whether it is $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: I’m guessing that “$(m,n)\Bbb Z$” is the infinite cyclic group generated by the element $(m,n)$ of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$. Is that right?

Comment: @Lubin Yes it is.

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255226/mathbbz-times-mathbbz-langle-1-2-rangle-is-isomorphic-to-what?rq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255071/mathbbz-times-mathbbz-langle-0-1-rangle?rq=1), etc.?

Comment: @DietrichBurde No, I was searching but found some less helpful answers. Thank you very much for pointing them.

Comment: Ah, I thought your notation meant $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue to the solution is that $\begin{pmatrix}m\\n\end{pmatrix}$ may be extended to a basis of $\Bbb Z^2$. Indeed, if $Am+Bn=1$, then
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix}m\\n\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}-B\\A\end{pmatrix}
\right\rbrace\,,
$$
is a basis, as you easily see. Thus the quotient by your subgroup is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.