# Proving Specific Quotient Group is Torsion-Free

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, torsion-groups

I am trying to prove that the quotient group $(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z})/(\mathbb{Z} \cdot (11,13))$ is torsion-free.

I know how I have to show that the only element in the group that has finite order is the identity, but I do not know where to start. I was trying to do contradiction, but did not make much progress.

I was also wondering if this can be generalized to other primes in $\mathbb{Z}$ other than 11,13?

Answer (score 2):

@Lord Shark's argument goes through for $(u,v)$ with $u$ and $v$ coprime.   See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2256367).  Thus, the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$...

Answer (score 1):

In effect you need to show that if $r(m,n)\in\Bbb Z(11,13)$
for $r\ne0$ then $(m,n)\in\Bbb Z(11,13)$.

You have $rm=11t$ and $rn=13t$ for some $t\in\Bbb Z$.
As $1=6\times 11-5\times 13$ (an instance of the Bezout
identity) then 
$$t=6(11t)-5(13t)=6rm-5rn$$
so that $r\mid t$. Then $(m,n)=(t/r)(11,13)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I believe I understand your argument, but I do not know why this is sufficient to showing torsion free.