# Classify $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\langle(0,3)\rangle$ according to the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am having an issue classifying $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\langle(0,3)\rangle$ according to  the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian group (i.e. finding what $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\langle(0,3)\rangle$ is isomorphic to). I think It should $\mathbb{Z}$, but I am not sure why. Thanks!

Comment: The element $(0,1)$ is of order $3$ and so the group can't be $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It goes like for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720900/classifying-the-factor-group-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-langle-2-2-ran?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not $\mathbb{Z}$. What is the order of (the coset) $[(0,1)]$?

You don't need the fundamental theorem at all. What you need is the following: if $G,G'$ are groups and $N\subseteq G$, $N'\subseteq G'$ are normal subgroups then $N\times N'$ is normal in $G\times G'$ and

$$(G\times G')/(N\times N')\simeq (G/N)\times (G'/N')$$

With that you can easily check that $\langle(0,3)\rangle=\{0\}\times 3\mathbb{Z}$ and so your group is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: What stops me from using $\{0\} \times 3 \mathbb{Z} \cong \{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and then concluding $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})/ (\{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @JonathanRayner $G/N$ need not be isomorphic to $G/N'$ even if $N$ and $N'$ are isomorphic. That conclusion is wrong.

Comment: Oh true, okay thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have

$\qquad \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} e_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z} e_2 $

$\qquad \langle(0,3)\rangle = \mathbb{Z} (0 e_1) \oplus \mathbb{Z} (3e_2) $

Therefore,

$\qquad \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\langle(0,3)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z_3}$

An explicit isomorphism is induced by $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}  
\mapsto (x, y \bmod 3) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z_3}$.