# What group is $\langle (1,1,1) \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I know that $\langle (1,1,1) \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$, but is there a way of writing what group it *is* (not what it's isomorphic to).

In other words, can we say that $\langle (1,1,1) \rangle$ is $G_1 \times G_2 \times G_3$ for some groups $G_1, G_2, G_3$?

I'm so used to using isomorphism that I can't tell if the answer is simply no. I tried using the Fundamental Theorem of Abelian Groups, but this didn't resolve my question.

---

For example, in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ we have $\langle (0,3) \rangle = \{0 \}  \times \mathbb{3Z}$.

We would often just say $\langle (0,3) \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$, but occasionally it's useful to *not* use the usual isomorphism and so this is what I'm asking for.

My motivation is to be able to more regularly use the trick used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2990411/90675).

Comment: It's a subgroup of order $40.$

Comment: If anything, this comment gives _less_ information than what I've written ("a subgroup of order 40" might not even be cyclic, but this particular one is). I'm asking for _more_ information.

Comment: The group $\langle (1,1) \rangle \subset \Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_8$ is not isomorphic to (and certainly not equal to) any product $G_2 \times G_3$.  Your group can be written as $\Bbb Z_5 \times \langle (1,1) \rangle$ (to the extent that we can consider the Cartesian product associative)

Comment: What do you mean what group it is as opposed to what group it is isomorphic to?  We usually name groups up to isomorphism, so your group is just $C_{40}$, which is the same as $\Bbb {Z_5 \times Z_8}$

Comment: Do you mean that you want a more explicit description of which _subset_ you have?

Comment: I suppose I should be more precise: $\langle (1,1) \rangle \subset \Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_8$ is not isomorphic to any **non-trivial** product

Comment: I've added a clarifying example above - I think @Omnomnomnom is coming closest to what I'm talking about?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690209/classify-mathbbz-5-times-mathbbz-4-times-mathbbz-8-langle1-1-1?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'd read that answer, but on second thought, I suppose you make a good point. I was hoping to do something "more direct" than Christoph's answer there, as per my edit above.

Comment: It *is* $\{(n,n,n) \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$, modulo $5$ in the first entry, modulo $4$ in the second entry, and modulo $8$ in the third entry, of course. If you wanted to write out all the elements specifically, you could start with $(1,1,1)$, $(2,2,2)$, $(3,3,3)$, $(4,0,4)$, $(0,1,5)$, $(1,2,6)$, and so on (where I am using representatives $\{0,1,2,3\}$ for $\mathbb Z_4$, etc.)

Comment: By the way, amongst all the groups in the universe that happen to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{40}$, you might well encounter some which do not have their own special names. I'll bet that there's some of them that you would **not** want to meet in a dark alley. The fact that the group in your question *does* have a special description as a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_ 4 \times \mathbb Z_8$ is pretty exceptional.

Comment: Fair enough! But I wasn't sure that for example, the fundamental theorem was enough for me to be certain. It definitely tells me what I _can_ do, but it wasn't clear to me that it tells me that _can't_ do what I wanted here. So then I wonder, what else do I need to know?

Comment: Aside: I need to think about it more to make sure the answer isn't just "Chinese Remainder Theorem" or something, but my next question was going to be something like "Suppose I want a set of $n$-tuples that is isomorphic to $G$ as an Abelian group. Can I classify what quotient groups or other ways of making this?" So maybe I'm looking for some dark alleys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\langle(1, 1, 1)\rangle$ is, as you said, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$, and the prime factorization of $40$ is $5 \times 8$, so we can say that $\langle(1, 1, 1)\rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_5 \times  \mathbb{Z}_8$. Now, it is important to convince yourself that such a group can't be expressed as the product of three subgroups, simply because $\mathbb{Z}_8$ can't be split since is cyclic and $\mathbb{Z}_5$ only has trivial subgroups, or, more formally, by contradiction, let $\langle(1, 1, 1)\rangle \simeq G_1 \times G_2 \times G_3 $. Since every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, $G_2 \times G_3$ is cyclic and none of its coordinates is $\{e\}$. Therefore, $ G_2 \times G_3 $ is a product of cyclic groups whose orders are multiples of $2$ (so they're not coprime) and it's cyclic, which is a contradiction. As for how you could use that other method in this case, i'd say the most it can do for you is to simplify the thing as $(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(1, 1, 1)\rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_5/\langle1\rangle \times (\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(1, 1)\rangle \simeq (\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(1, 1)\rangle$, but since that $\langle(1, 1)\rangle$ is not a product of subgroups you have to figure out some other way to find it. I hope to have answered your question, let me know if that's not the case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking in your question, but if I'm understanding it, I hope this will help.

One way to think about it is the following. If $q:\Bbb{Z}/(8)\to \Bbb{Z}/(4)$ is the quotient map, then the elements of the subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}/(5)\times \Bbb{Z}/(4)\times \Bbb{Z}/(8)$ generated by $(1,1,1)$ are precisely the elements of the form $(i,q(j),j)$, with $i\in\Bbb{Z}/(5)$, and $j\in\Bbb{Z}/(8)$. This also makes the isomorphism with $\Bbb{Z}/(5)\times \Bbb{Z}/(8)$ clear. One direction is $(i,q(j),j)\mapsto (i,j)$, and the other is $(i,j)\mapsto (i,q(j),j)$.

**Side note:**

This isn't directly related to your question, just an interesting tangent.

If we focus on the subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}/(8)\times \Bbb{Z}/(4)$ generated by $(1,1)$ (order deliberately flipped here), we can see that it is the subgroup $(j,q(j))$ for $j\in \Bbb{Z}/(8)$, which you can think of as the graph of the group homomorphism $q$. It's quite often the case that when you can construct the graph of a morphism $f$, the graph turns out to be isomorphic to the starting object, with one of the isomorphisms being $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$, and the other being $(x,f(x))\mapsto x$.

Comment: Its beautiful. I have a doubt. Can you explain a bit more on the phrase "... is the quotient map, then...". What does it mean? Is it $q(x) = x (\mod 4)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but here's a way to see that $(\Bbb Z_{4} \times \Bbb Z_8)/\langle (1,1) \rangle \cong \Bbb Z_4$.  We note that the map $\phi:\Bbb Z_{4} \times \Bbb Z_8 \to \Bbb Z_{4} \times \Bbb Z_8$ defined by $\phi: (x,y) \mapsto (x-y,y)$ is a group automorphism (which is induced by the automorphism with the same formula from $\Bbb Z^2$ to $\Bbb Z^2$).  It follows that
$$
(\Bbb Z_{4} \times \Bbb Z_8)/\langle (1,1) \rangle \cong \phi(\Bbb Z_{4} \times \Bbb Z_8)/\phi(\langle (1,1) \rangle) = 
(\Bbb Z_{4} \times \Bbb Z_8)/\langle (0,1) \rangle\\
\quad \  = (\Bbb Z_4  \times \Bbb Z_8)/(\{0\} \times \Bbb Z_8) \cong \Bbb Z_4
$$

Comment: Thank you for writing this - I accepted the other answer because I think it answered what I technically asked for in the question and it would have been unfair not to. But your answer was very helpful and exactly in the spirit of what I was looking for!