# Classification of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \langle (n,n,n) \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, quotient-group, direct-product

I want to classify the abelian groups of the form

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \langle (n,n,n) \rangle
\end{align}
using fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

From my previous post [Classifying $ \frac{\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}}{\langle(n,n)\rangle}$ via fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045661/classifying-frac-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-langlen-n-rangle-via-funda), I understand for $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} / \langle (n,n) \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_n$.

The easy way to see this is by considering its generators. $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} = \langle (1,1), (1,0) \rangle$ and moding out $n(1,1)$ I have the above expression.

Is the same procedure can apply for higher rank case? I mean generalization of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ mod by group generated by $n(1,\cdots, 1)$?

For $k=3$, $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} = \langle (1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,1)\rangle $ and in this time I cannot mod $(1,1,1)$ freely....

Comment: Use the free generating set $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: @Derek Holt, If I mod out with $(1,1,1)$, then $\langle (1,0,0), (0,1,0) \rangle$, then am I get $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: If you want to tackle problems in this class more generally then the Smith Normal Form is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can use the Smith normal form to get your result. However, we can simply notice that $e_1=(1,1,\ldots ,1),e_2=(0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots, e_k=(0,0,\ldots,0,1)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ (easy: the base change matrix is upper triangular with determinant $1$).

Hence $\mathbb{Z}^k=\mathbb{Z}e_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_2\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_k$, while $\mathbb{Z}(n,n,\ldots,n)=n\mathbb{Z}e_1$.

The first isomorphism theorem applied to $f:\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k a_i e_i\in \mathbb{Z}^k\mapsto (\overline{a}_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$ shows that your quotient group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}.$